# Most efficient method to allow users to determine the validity of Exit Codes

Tags: c#, windows, process, exit-code

I've noticed that the Process Exit Code integers returned by different processes in Windows don't seem to follow any specific format (e.g. less than 1 is not necessarily an error, etc), so as part of my application, which allows users to launch processes, I would like the user to be able to define exit code success criteria generically.  I'm not particularly familiar with use of Exit Codes however, so am wondering what the most efficient form for the options which would allow user complete coverage would be, for instance, I can add any number of options:

- Fail if Exit Code Less Than - int
- Fail if Exit Code Greater Than -int
- Succeed if Exit Code Equals - int
- Fail if Exit Code within Range (int, int)
- Fail if Exit Code Not Equal to (list of int)

and more.  Can anyone who has knowledge of how these codes are normally used suggest the choices which would allow users the greatest/complete coverage of all scenarios with the least number of different additional parameters for the user to choose from, or would it really be better to simply allow the user to enter some sort of condition expression themselves, with basic logic functions?

Comment: And you're worried about runtime performance? I don't get it. The title seems largely unrelated to the question.

Comment: The only standard I'm aware of is that an exit code of 0 means success. Anything else is up to the individual application's discretion. However, you should stick to an unsigned 16-bit value for maximum compatibiilty.

Comment: To clarify the use of the word 'efficient' for @EdPlunkett, by efficient, I simply mean the least number of extra options, as opposed to providing all of the above, plus alternates for each one with 'Succeed if' and more, to make the usage of the application simple.

Comment: Error codes are for applications; error messages are for users.

Comment: @seekingknowledge Yes, I noticed that you weren't talking about efficiency. I was trying to make that point in my previous comment.

Comment: It is simply the value that the programmer returns from his main() entrypoint.  The only convention is that 0 means "no error" and anything else is a value that the programmer chose to indicate a failure reason.  Noteworthy is what happens when the program crashed before it reached the end of main() and was forcefully terminated by the OS.  You then get a large negative value that indicates the SEH exception code.

Comment: In most cases, success is indicated by a particular code, which is usually, but not always, zero.  So that's going to be the most commonly used option.  `robocopy` returns anything from 0 to 3 on success, if I remember rightly, so the range option would also be useful, and I imagine the list option would be useful occasionally.  "Less than" and "greater than" options would be used very rarely if at all.  Note that exit codes are 32-bit and are sometimes treated as signed and sometimes as unsigned, you should probably accept either.  It would also be useful to accept hexadecimal numbers.